# SignalR implementation for MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I want to use SignalR in my mvc 3 project. I have ticket system like "basecamp" or "donedone", so when a new ticket assigned to any user in the system, these users should be notified. Old system should be working with jquery timer and in every 1 minute should check the database to see if there is a new ticket.

But as i read about SignalR, i can actually trigger something on server side which triggers client side. But i don't know if i can implement this on my app. For example, i have a business layer to do db operations. So can i trigger SignalR Hub when i create a new ticket. Are there examples for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also blogged about implementing something similar to your requirements using SignalR.  A call to a web service in my case triggers updating specific client browsers with updated statistics.

[Adding realtime statistics to surveywizz](http://www.woohoo.uk.com/Blog/adding-real-time-statistics-to-surveywizz-using-signalr)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is indeed possible. Please take a look at the section titled "Broadcasting over a Hub from outside of a Hub" at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs